# Can't find the name of my Vertex Group

Tags: vertex-groups

I am encountering a very strange problem. I have assigned a vertex group in my shrinkwrap modifier some time ago. Then I worked with my rig that has a lot vertex groups for my deformation bones. I can see that the vertex group "NoShrink" of the object is assigned in the Shrinkwrap modifier. But I could not find it in the vertex groups of the object data properties. The modifier accepts this non-existing group and works properly. Now I want to change the weights of the vertices in the vertex group but I can't find it. What could have happened? Is it hidden? I have never heard of any way to hide the name of the vertex group in object data properties window. I searched it by typing the name in search box, also I scrolled down manually through all those vertex groups carefully a couple of times and still its missing. But the shrinkwrap modifier has this vertex group assigned to it and shows no error. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The vertex group must be in the object that has the Shrinkwrap modifier, not the target object, is it the case here?

Comment: No that is not the case here. Its actually the same object. The target object 'head' does not have any vertex groups. Moreover this modifier is on the 'body' object so I will not be able to select any vertex group of the 'head' object. The thing is: The modifier works normally as long as I don't erase the vertex group name in the modifier. Once I erase it I can't add it again. Which means that it does not exist. If I delete all the vertex groups of the object then the modifier shows an error. I do not understand why it does not show its name in the Vertex groups of the object data properties.

Comment: Could you please share your file? Only keep the useful objects https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I have shared the file. I have to delete the target 'head' object too because its huge. But you don't need it. The problem is still the same.

Comment: So what object is supposed to shrinkwrap onto what object?

Comment: The 'body' object is supposed to shrink wrap on an hi-poly model named as 'head' which just the hi-poly version of this 'body' object. I deleted it because its over 300mb. I made the 'NoShrink' vertex group to exclude the inner mouth and eye area from shrinking into the hi-poly model. The problem is: You can see the "NoShrink" vertex group in the modifier but you can't find the name in the vertex groups of the object data properties.

Comment: Yes that's weird but what about creating a new vertex group in the vertex group list then select it in the modifier?

Comment: Yes that will work. I am just wondering where my 'NoShrink' vertex group is. It shouldn't just vanish like that. If the modifier is able to accept the vertex group then it must be somewhere. So where can it be? why is it not listed in the vertex groups?

Comment: You must have deleted it accidentally, you can test it yourself, select a vertex group in the Shrinkwrap, then delete it in the Vertex Groups lists, the vertex group will still be displayed in the modifier

Comment: You are right. I created a new vertex group and added it to a new shrinkwrap modifier. Then I deleted the vertex group but it still appears in the shrinkwrap modifier. It only shows a error in the shrinkwrap modifier if I delete all the groups. Seems like the modifier is not taking a reference, instead it is taking a copy of the vertex data, which is  strange. Because then in that case it should not show an error even if I delete all the vertex groups. Anyway I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: in any case since the modifier is somehow holding that vertex group data even after deleting it from the vertex groups of the of the object data properties, is there any way to get that vertex group back?

Comment: No you need to recreate the vertex group in the Vertex Groups list and reassign to the vertices, the blend file has not kept the vertex group somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have deleted the vertex group accidentally but it still appears in the *Shrinkwrap* modifier nevertheless. You can test it yourself, select a vertex group in the *Shrinkwrap*, then delete it in the *Vertex Groups* list, the vertex group will still be displayed in the modifier. You can't recover this vertex group, you need to recreate it in the *Vertex Groups* list and assign the vertices you want.